# Derivative and Power transformation

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth strictly increasing function defined on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$. Suppose the right derivative $f'(0+)=0$. Is the following statement true?

Statement: Given such a $f(x)$, there exists a constant $\varepsilon>0$ such that $g(x)=(f(x))^\varepsilon$ has a positive first right derivative at $x=0$, that is, $g'(0+)>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$.  Then for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $$g(x)=(f(x))^\epsilon=e^{\frac{-\epsilon}{x^2}}$$ which satisfies $g'(0)=0$.